# Power BI y datos temporales

Tags: powerbi

De primeras gracias por la ayuda a todo aquel que se interese en contestar.
Mi duda es simple pero no he encontrado hasta el momento ninguna forma de hacerlo, me gustaría saber si de alguna forma yo podrá simular un aumento por ejemplo de el coste del agua mensual.

Vamos a poner esta situación, tengo mi power bi con datos extraidos de un excel en donde aparece el coste de mi factura del agua que tendrá X litros gastados en el mes y X precio el litro.Cuando yo saco todo el cálculo en BI, podría de alguna forma simular que mi coste a aumentado 5 euros y que todos los cálculos se me aplicaran con ese nuevo incremento.

Gracias y saludos a la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que quieres, se me ocurren dos posibilidades.

- La primera es crear una tabla manual, con los valores que tu quieras, por ejemplo de 1 as 100, que corresponderían a euros. O puede que un porcentaje. Luego creas una medida que sume el valor a tu dato del precio. Pones un visual a modo de filtro con la tabla creada y según tome un valor u otro se recalculará el informe.
- Otra forma de hacerlo, aunque parecida, es utilizando la funcionalidad de Hipótesis (What-if en inglés), botón Parámetro nuevo en Modelado. Esto automatiza lo que puse en el punto anterior. [Aquí](http://blog.blauservices.com/?p=1685) tienes un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]